# False value when I use a Getter for ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, setter, getter

I have two classes, A and B. In the first one (A), I have a comboBox with some items, I'd like to get the selected item in the second class (B) (by clicking on a certain button).

So I made a getter for the comboBox, but everytime I call the getter in the second class, I get the very first item, even if it's not selected.

Here's the code of the getter (1st class (A)):

```
public String getModuleSelected(){
        return comboModule.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
```

Here's how I get the selected Item (class B):

```
A moy = new A();
System.out.println(moy.getModuleSelected());
```

It always show the first very item of the comboBox. Even if it's not selected. I tried the getter in its own class (A), and it worked, I got the right selected Item after I clicked on the button. But when I try it with another class, I get an Item, but always the first one.

Comment: This type of question, "why is this code not working", almost always requires that you create and post a working [mcve] for us to be able to understand the problem and answer adequately. Please consider doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
A moy = new A();  // ******* this line****
System.out.println(moy.getModuleSelected());
```

You're creating a new `A` object, one that is not the same as the displayed A object, one that has not had any selection done on it, and it will not have the same state as the displayed object.

The solution is to not do this, to not create a new `A` object, but rather to call the `getModuleSelected()` only on the currently displayed and active `A` object. You'll need to get a valid reference to this object, something your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us help you with. Note that this would often be done through a constructor or setter method parameter.